# python loop for web-scraping

Tags: python

I'am trying to create a loop to show all values within the li tags to create a DataFrame. Moreover, I can only isolate the code using: new = soup.find("div", class_="PlayerList"). If I use a standard for loop it only shows one value not all values.

The output I would like to show is:

Messi,

Shooting 9,

Passing 9,

Tackle 4,

```
   <pre>
   import requests
   import pandas as pd
   import numpy as np

   from urllib.request import urlopen
   from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

   main_url = 'https://examplelistpython.000webhostapp.com/messi.html'
   result = requests.get(main_url)
   result.text

   soup = BeautifulSoup(result.text, 'html.parser')
   print(soup.prettify())

   new  = soup.find("div", class_="PlayerList")
   new

    </pre>

<ul class="List">
 <li>
  <div class="PlayerList">
   <div class="HeaderList">
    <span class="player">Messi</span>
</div>
  <div class="PlayerStat">
   <span class="stat">Shooting   <span class="allStatContainer statShooting" data-stat="Shooting">
     9
  </span>
 </span>
</div>
<div class="PlayerStat">
<span class="stat">Passing   <span class="allStatContainer statPassing" data-stat="Passing">
  9
 </span>
</span>
</div>
<div class="PlayerStat">
<span class="stat">Tackle   <span class="allStatContainer statTackle" data-stat="Tackle">
     4
     </span>
   </span>
  </div>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It that website working? It is showing error while using get() of requests

Comment: Yes. It should be working? Which code are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
player = [i.text.strip() for i in soup.find_all("span", class_="player")]
shooting = [i.text.strip() for i in soup.find_all("span", class_="allStatContainer statShooting")]
passing = [i.text.strip() for i in soup.find_all("span", class_="allStatContainer statPassing")] 
tackle = [i.text.strip() for i in soup.find_all("span", class_="allStatContainer statTackle")]

df = pd.DataFrame({'Player': player, 'Shooting': shooting, 'Passing': passing, 'Tackle': tackle})
```

Result:

|  | Player | Shooting | Passing | Tackle |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Messi | 9 | 9 | 4 |